# Create custom exceptions in Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I'm using Axis2 1.5.2 and Eclipse. I'm using Eclipse to generate the WSDL and client code from generated WSDL.

I created a custom exception that my service can throw.  Everything looks ok when creating the webservice.  The webservice starts successfully and I can view the generated WSDL by pointing my web browser.
But when I tell Eclipse to generate the Client code using the generated WSDL I get this error from Eclipse:

```
Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: ERROR: Missing <soap:fault> element inFault "InsertUserException" in operation "InsertUserException", in binding insertUser
    java.io.IOException: ERROR: Missing <soap:fault> element inFault "InsertUserException" in operation "InsertUserException", in binding insertUser
    at org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.faultsFromSOAPFault(SymbolTable.java:2858)
```

My custom exception is "InsertUserException":

```
public class InsertUserException extends Exception{
  private String errorCode;

  public InsertUserException(String errorCode){.....}
  public String getErrorCode(){...}
  public void setErrorCode(String errorCode){...}

}
```

My service action that clients can call is "insertUser":

```
public void insertUser() throws  InsertUserException{
.....
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axis2 doesn't know how to send Exceptions over the wire unless they are AxisFaults.

Here's a link to an article on how to use AxisFault with custom exception information.

http://wso2.org/library/171

Comment: I thought Axis2 would somehow do the conversion but this solution works for me. Thanks.