# An Issue with Axis2 Web Service Framework

Tags: java, apache-axis

I’m writing a web service (and client) in Java by using Axis2. In one of the web methods I want to throw an exception and in the client side I am going to catch this exception. Unfortunately it seems like this is not an easy task to do with Axis2.

Does anybody have an idea about how to do it in Axis2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this post answer your question? I believe you just need to make sure your service throws an AxisFault. There are more details in the post.

[Create custom exceptions in Axis2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954632/create-custom-exceptions-in-axis2)