# Axis 2 Client not receiving a thrown exception from an Axis 2 Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

An Axis 2 client (wsdl2java generated code) invoking  an Axis 2 Webservice is not receiving a RuntimeException thrown from a Service. The invoked method is a **void method**.

The Axis 2 version I'm using for both client and server is 1.6.1.

When I run the following **test** it completes successfully and no Exception is received:

```
@Test
public void testMyService() throws RemoteException {
    String target = "http://localhost:8080/services/MyService";
    MyServiceStub myServiceStub = new MyServiceStub(target);
    myServiceStub.doSomething();
}
```

**MyService.java:**

```
package com.afirme.webservice.service;

@Service
public class MyService {

    public void doSomething() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Just testing!");
    }

}
```

**services.xml:**

```
<serviceGroup>
    <service name="MyService">
        <description>
            My Service
        </description>
         <messageReceivers>
                <messageReceiver 
                    mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only"
            class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
                <messageReceiver
                    mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"
            class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
        </messageReceivers>
         <parameter name="ServiceObjectSupplier">org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringServletContextObjectSupplier</parameter>
         <parameter name="SpringBeanName">myService</parameter>
    </service>  
</serviceGroup>
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954632/create-custom-exceptions-in-axis2). You need to throw an `AxisFault`.

Comment: So what did you actually try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operation is an in only one. So you won't receive any soap faults from that. If you want to throw faults your operation must be an in-out one.